# How to convert mouse input to python array?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, jupyter

I want to convert mouse double click 2D coordinates to an array. This is the code I have so far:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

ix,iy = -1,-1
# mouse callback function
def draw_circle(event,x,y,flags,param):
    global ix,iy
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDBLCLK:
        cv2.circle(img,(x,y),10,(255,0,0),-1)
        ix,iy = x,y

# Create a black image, a window and bind the function to window
img = np.zeros((1000,1000,3), np.uint8)
cv2.namedWindow('image')
cv2.setMouseCallback('image',draw_circle)

physNodes =[]

while(1):
    img = cv2.imread('RPE.jpg')
    cv2.imshow('image',img)
    k = cv2.waitKey(20) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:
        break
    elif k == ord('a'):
        Nodes =[ix,iy]
        physNodes.append(Nodes)
        #print(physNodes)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

You can load any kind of image to reproduce. I am running this code in a jupyter notebook and encounter the problem that I can't close the window. 
But what I actually want to ask is how I can fill an array with the incoming user input. Thanks!

Comment: What is wrong with this code? I tested it and it works, when you double click it changes the coordinates, and when you press a it appends it to physNodes... and when 'esc' key is pressed it exits and closes all windows. I did not tested in Jupyter though.... what is actually doing in your case? could it be a jupyter problem perhaps?

Comment: Thanks for testing it! Indeed looks like a Jupyter problem then..